# How to mock AbortController in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking, redux-saga

I have a `Redux` saga that makes several API requests. I am using `takeLatest` to make sure that any previously running sagas are cancelled if a new action is fired. However this does not cancel in-flight requests and we are running into max connection limit issues.

To fix this I am creating an AbortController inside the saga and passing it to each request so they can be aborted if the saga is cancelled (see below):

```js
export function* doSomething(action: Action): SagaIterator {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    try {
        const fooResponse: FooResponse = yield call(getFoo, ..., abortController);
        ...
        const barResponse: BarResponse = yield call(getBar, ..., abortController);
    }
    catch {
        .. handle error
    }
    finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            abortController.abort(); // Cancel the API call if the saga was cancelled
        }
    }
}

export function* watchForDoSomethingAction(): SagaIterator {
  yield takeLatest('action/type/app/do_something', doSomething);
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to check that `abortController.abort()` is called, since AbortController is instantiated inside the saga.  Is there a way to mock this?

Answer (score 6):

In order to test the `AbortController`'s `abort` function I mocked the `global.AbortController` inside my test.

Example:

```js
const abortFn = jest.fn();

// @ts-ignore
global.AbortController = jest.fn(() => ({
  abort: abortFn,
}));

await act(async () => {
  // ... Trigger the cancel function
});

// expect the mock to be called
expect(abortFn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to create mock for `AbortController.prototype.abort` method. Then, execute the saga generator, test it by each step. Simulate the cancellation using `gen.return()` method.

My test environment is `node`, so I use [abortcontroller-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill) to polyfill `AbortController`.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { AbortController, abortableFetch } from 'abortcontroller-polyfill/dist/cjs-ponyfill';
import _fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { SagaIterator } from 'redux-saga';
import { call, cancelled, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
const { fetch } = abortableFetch(_fetch);

export function getFoo(abortController) {
  return fetch('http://localhost/api/foo', { signal: abortController.signal });
}

export function* doSomething(): SagaIterator {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  try {
    const fooResponse = yield call(getFoo, abortController);
  } catch {
    console.log('handle error');
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      abortController.abort();
    }
  }
}

export function* watchForDoSomethingAction(): SagaIterator {
  yield takeLatest('action/type/app/do_something', doSomething);
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { AbortController } from 'abortcontroller-polyfill/dist/cjs-ponyfill';
import { call, cancelled } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { doSomething, getFoo } from './saga';

describe('66588109', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const abortSpy = jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'abort');
    const gen = doSomething();
    expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(call(getFoo, expect.any(AbortController)));
    expect(gen.return!().value).toEqual(cancelled());
    gen.next(true);
    expect(abortSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    abortSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/66588109/saga.test.ts
  66588109
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |       50 |   33.33 |   78.57 |                   
 saga.ts  |      75 |       50 |   33.33 |   78.57 | 8,16,25           
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.801 s
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a shot... I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution than spying on the prototype chain, but it seems like that might be the only option... thanks!